# C Program to determine whether the given tree is Binary Search Tree or not?

Tags: c, recursion, data-structures, binary-search-tree

I am writing the below code in C Programming language to determine whether a given tree is binary search tree or not. But I am getting a segmentation error. Can anyone help me in understanding what I am doing wrong here?

```
struct node {
    int val;
    struct node *left;
    struct node *right;
};

int isBST(struct node* root) {
    if(root == NULL) {
        return 1;
    }
    if(root->left->val >= root->val || root->right->val <= root->val) {
        return 0;
    }
    return (isBST(root->left) && isBST(root->right));
}
```

I am trying to check if the value of the left node is lower than the value of the current node and value of the right node is greater than the value of the current node. Also using recursion, I am repeating this process for the left and right subtrees. I was expecting a true or false but got the segmentation error.

Comment: you haven't handled NULL pointer for left and right sub trees. what if it's a leaf node which doesn't have any child ? or any intermediate node with only one child ?

Comment: `root->left->val` is bad. Even if `root` isn't NULL (which you check), `root->left` may be NULL so you can't be sure that the access to `val` is valid.

Comment: To keep the code simple I would split the `if` statement into two `if` statements. Like `if(root->left && root->left->val >= root->val) return 0;` and a similar `if`  for the  right node.

Comment: OT: An interresting read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/300935/are-duplicate-keys-allowed-in-the-definition-of-binary-search-trees

Comment: The algorithm is wrong even if you fix the null pointer access. Check with the tree (10 (5 (1 20) 15 (1 20)).

Comment: Also answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47610394/509868), with more readable code than what we currently have below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A binary search tree is a binary tree where the value of each node is larger than all values in the left subtree and smaller than all values in the right subtree.

The OP code has two issues:

- There is no check for the `left` or `right` pointers being `NULL`.
- The condition that the current value is larger than the value of the left child node and smaller than the value of the right child node is a *necessary*, but not *sufficient* condition for a binary search tree.

For example, if the root node has value `10` and a left node with value `5` which again has a right node with value `15`, then the check of immediate child nodes will pass, but the tree is not a binary search tree.

The idea of the following implementation is to traverse the tree in order as a binary search tree and verify that the nodes are actually in order which is the case if and only if the tree is a binary search tree:

```
// Helper function for traversal and checking order
int isBSTTraversal(struct node* root, struct node** prev) {
    if(root == NULL) {
        return 1;
    }
    if(!isBSTTraversal(root->left, prev)) {
        return 0;  // Left subtree not BST
    }
    if(*prev != NULL && root->val < (*prev)->val) {
        return 0;  // Visited values are out of order: not a BST
    }
    *prev = root;
    return isBSTTraversal(root->right, prev);
}

int isBST(struct node* root) {
    struct node* prev = NULL;
    return isBSTTraversal(root, &prev);
}
```

Comment: @anastaciu ChatGPT is wrong, also in this case. I have no further comment than my initial one.

Comment: Perhaps, and if it's found that that is the case I apologise in advance.

Comment: ChatGPT accusation is discussed [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/426545/509868). Not sure it helps. Anyway, this answer is good in my opinion; +1.

Comment: @anastaciu (1) I fully support any effort to get rid of AI generated answers, but at the same time I find it very unpleasant to be falsely accused. Let me explain how this answer was constructed. First, I read the question and comments. To set the goal straight, I summarized the definition of a BST. Then, I mentioned the issues in the OP solution which had already been pointed out by "Support Ukraine" and "n. m. could be an AI" (thanks to both). The key issue is that "local checks" are not sufficient so I tried to explain that as simply as possible. Then I thought about the simplest...

Comment: (2) ... way to implement the check correctly and found that doing a traversal and check the order was probably the simplest way. Then I googled and found a pseudocode implementation [here](https://www.enjoyalgorithms.com/blog/validate-binary-search-tree). I then convinced myself that this method was correct and wrote the code in C using the context of the OP. Admittedly, I did not spend much time considering optimizations (my day time job has priority), but user chqrlie was kind to point out improvements in a now removed comment which I implemented (second edit).

Comment: I'll admit my first comment was not ok since it can be interpreted as a fact, and for that I apologise, I don't know and I have no reason to not believe you, at the same time the answer's setup led me to doubt and make a very superficial attempt to confirm or dismiss my suspicion. Again, if I'm wrong I'm sorry and I will go so far as to delete my comments since they are not needed and the matter is already being addressed.

Comment: @anastaciu You cannot use AI to confirm whether something is AI. It is completely unreliable.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar, sure. I did 3 things, firstly I asked the AI, secondly I asked the question as in OP and 3rd I passed it through a AI content detector. Anyway, nielsen already clarified it, I already apologised for not addressing the issue the right way.